# Rails6においてform forでのエラーが発生する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form

## 前提・実現したいこと

現在、インスタクローンアプリでコメント機能を実装中です。
投稿一覧画面に直接コメント一覧とコメント投稿フォームも表示したいと考えています。

## 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
ArgumentError in MainPage#main
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

## 該当のソースコード

関連があると思われるコードを以下に記載します。
main_page_controller.rb

```
class MainPageController < ApplicationController
  def main
    if logged_in?
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
end
```

micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :love_users, through: :likes, source: :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :picture, presence: true
  validate  :picture_size

  def love(user)
    likes.create(user_id: user.id)
  end

  def unlove(user)
    likes.find_by(user_id: user.id).destroy
  end

  def love?(user)
    love_users.include?(user)
  end

  private

    def picture_size
      if picture.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:picture, "画像サイズを5MB以下にしてください")
      end
    end
end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost
  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

microposts_controller.rb

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "投稿しました"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "投稿を削除しました"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  def new
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build if logged_in?
  end

  def show 
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new
    @user = User.find_by(id: @micropost.user_id)
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "投稿しました"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "投稿できませんでした"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private 

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

micropost.html.rb

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>" data-micropost-id="<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, size: 50), micropost.user %>
  <%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %>
  <span class="content">
    <%= micropost.content %>
    <%= image_tag micropost.picture.url if micropost.picture? %>
  </span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %>前に投稿
    <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
      <%= link_to "削除", micropost, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "削除してもよろしいですか？" } %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
  <%= render "likes/like", micropost: micropost %>
  <div class="comment_index">
    <% @micropost.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>
      <%= comment.content %>
      <span class="delete">
        <%= link_to "削除", [@micropost, comment], method: :delete if current_user?(comment.user) %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-form">
    <%= form_for([@micropost, @comment]) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "コメントを入力" %>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "投稿", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</li>
```

## 試したこと、仮説

エラー文では１つ目の引数がnilか空っぽであると言っていますが、Mainpage#mainでは@micropostの定義を行っています。
また、コンソールでmicropostのデータを試しに作成したところ、正常に作成できました。
加えて、main_page_controller.rbに@micropost=Micropost.newの一文も追加してみると良さそうだと調査の結果わかったのでそれも試してみましたが、効果はありませんでした。
考えられる要因は見て回りましたがそれでも解消されませんでした。お力をお借りできればと思います。

## 補足情報

rails (6.0.2.1)
[コメント機能作成にあたり参考にしたサイト](https://qiita.com/krppppp/items/7f9563e08150a008592f)

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/254164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これまでは投稿一覧ページに直接コメントとコメント投稿フォームを表示させようとしていましたが、micropost表示ページを別に作成し、そこに表示させることで実装しました。